# Why doesn't my click work immediately in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I am recreating mine sweeper.

My code goes through every square on a 800 by 600 display and each square is 50 by 50 so there are 192 squares.
I check to see if the click is in each square and draw a bomb or an open space depending on what it is.

```
def check_for_click(x_click,  y_click, x_square, y_square, x_circle, y_circle, a_round, a_count):
    if x_click < x_square and y_click < y_square and x_click > (x_square - 50) and y_click > (y_square - 50):
        if grid[(a_round - 1)][(a_count)] == 1:
            bomb.play()
            choose = random.randint(0, 6)
            the_color = random.choice(light_colors[choose])
            make_square(the_color, (x_square - 50), (y_square - 50))
            the_color = random.choice(dark_colors[choose])
            make_circle(the_color, x_circle, y_circle)
            pygame.display.update()
        if grid[(a_round - 1)][(a_count)] == 0:
            the_grass.play()
            make_square(light_brown, (x_square - 50), (y_square - 50))
            pygame.display.update()
            grid[(a_round - 1)][(a_count)] = 2
```

The above function checks to see if the click was in a certain square

```
word = True
while word:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            word = False
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            click = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            check = True
            while check == True:
                round = 1
                count = 0
                the_x = 50
                the_y = 50
                cir_x = 25
                cir_y = 25
                x = click[0]
                y = click[1]
                for i in range(12):
                    for i in range(16):
                        check_for_click(x, y, the_x, the_y, cir_x, cir_y, round, count)
                        the_x = the_x + 50
                        cir_x = cir_x + 50
                        count = count + 1
                    the_y = the_y + 50
                    cir_y = cir_y + 50
                    the_x = 50
                    cir_x = 25
                    count = 0
                    round = round + 1
                check = False
```

Above is the game loop and then it goes into a while loop every time you click and checks every square position to see if the click was inside of it

```
    update_score()
    draw_numbers()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Above are some more functions that I wrote but not include for the sake of brevity.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work immediately"? When does it work then? Please explain in more detail what you expect to happen vs. what actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the messages and remove them from the queue. See the documentation:

> This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue. [...]

If `pygame.event.get()` is called in multiple event loops, only one loop receives the events, but never all loops receive all events. As a result, some events appear to be missed.

Call `pygame.event.get()` just once:

```py
word = True
    while word:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                word = False

        # for event in pygame.event.get(): <--- DELETE
        
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                click = event.pos

                # [...]
```